# Expand an R data.table by rows via column not in that data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following R data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread('unique_point biased    data_points   team   groupID                                                                                                           
 up1          FALSE     3             1      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 up1          TRUE      4             22     xy28352                                                                                                                 
 up2          FALSE     1             4      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 up2          TRUE      0             3      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 up3          FALSE     12            5      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 up3          TRUE      35            7      xy28352')
```

Printed is as follows:

```
DT
    unique_point biased    data_points   team   groupID                                                                                                           
 1: up1          FALSE     3             1      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 2: up1          TRUE      4             22     xy28352                                                                                                                 
 3: up2          FALSE     1             4      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 4: up2          TRUE      0             3      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 5: up3          FALSE     12            5      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 6: up3          TRUE      35            7      xy28352 
 ....
```

At the moment, each `unique_point` has two rows, with a `biased` value `TRUE` and `FALSE`. I would like to expand `DT` such that there are 6 rows for each `unique_point` in the following format:

```
    unique_point biased    type    data_points   team   groupID                                                                                                           
 1: up1          FALSE     A       3             1      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 2: up1          TRUE      A       4             22     xy28352                                                                                                                 
 3: up1          FALSE     B       0             1      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 4: up1          TRUE      B       0             22     xy28352                                                                                                                  
 5: up1          FALSE     C       0             1      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 6: up1          TRUE      C       0             22     xy28352 
 7: up2          FALSE     A       1             4      xy28352
 ...
```

That is, for each unique point, there would be a FALSE/TRUE with A, B, and C.

I began with the following code:

```
> DT2 <- DT[, .SD[CJ(type=c("A", "B", "C"), biased = biased, unique = TRUE), 
                on = .(biased, type)], by = .(unique_point)][]
```

I get the following error

```
Error in `[.data.table`(.SD, CJ(variants = c("SNP", "INS", "DEL"), fused = fused,  :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   Column(s) [variants] not found in x
```

So, I used the following hack to create a new column in `DT` named `type`, with at least these three unique values:

```
DT$type[2] = "A"
DT$type[4] = "B"
DT$type[6] = "C"
```

The above code then works.

What is the correct way to expand `DT` via the `type` categories `A`, `B`, `C` without using this "trick"? The way I have done this now is not standard, and could confused third-parties. Readable code and learning why my original attempt doesn't work is the goal.

EDIT: Actually, I think the dimensions are wrong. My solution has bugs.

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for a `data.table` specific solution?

Comment: @ChiPak Yes, though I'm ok with `dataframe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try:

```
DT2 <- DT[CJ(type = LETTERS[1:3], biased = biased, unique_point = unique_point, unique = TRUE),
   on = .(unique_point, biased), nomatch = 0]

#     unique_point biased data_points team groupID type
#  1:          up1  FALSE           3    1 xy28352    A
# 2:          up2  FALSE           1    4 xy28352    A
# 3:          up3  FALSE          12    5 xy28352    A
# 4:          up1   TRUE           4   22 xy28352    A
# 5:          up2   TRUE           0    3 xy28352    A
# 6:          up3   TRUE          35    7 xy28352    A
# 7:          up1  FALSE           3    1 xy28352    B
# 8:          up2  FALSE           1    4 xy28352    B
# 9:          up3  FALSE          12    5 xy28352    B
# 10:          up1   TRUE           4   22 xy28352    B
# 11:          up2   TRUE           0    3 xy28352    B
# 12:          up3   TRUE          35    7 xy28352    B
# 13:          up1  FALSE           3    1 xy28352    C
# 14:          up2  FALSE           1    4 xy28352    C
# 15:          up3  FALSE          12    5 xy28352    C
# 16:          up1   TRUE           4   22 xy28352    C
# 17:          up2   TRUE           0    3 xy28352    C
# 18:          up3   TRUE          35    7 xy28352    C
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a helper dataframe or datatable, *abc_DT* where you run a cross join with it on main table. Additionally, use a conditional `ifelse` to fill zeros in *data_points* column for expanded rows.

**data.table**

```
abc_DT <- data.table(type=c("A", "B", "C"), data_points_=0)

# CROSS JOIN                     
DT2 <- setkey(DT[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[abc_DT[,c(k=1,.SD)],allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]
# RE-ORDER ROWS
DT2 <- DT2[order(unique_point, type, biased)]

# CONDITIONAL ASSIGNMENT AND RE-ORDER COLS
setcolorder(DT2[, data_points:= ifelse(type=="A",  data_points,  data_points_)][,data_points_:=NULL], 
            c("unique_point", "biased", "type", "data_points", "team", "groupID"))
DT2
#     unique_point biased type data_points team groupID
#  1:          up1  FALSE    A           3    1 xy28352
#  2:          up1   TRUE    A           4   22 xy28352
#  3:          up1  FALSE    B           0    1 xy28352
#  4:          up1   TRUE    B           0   22 xy28352
#  5:          up1  FALSE    C           0    1 xy28352
#  6:          up1   TRUE    C           0   22 xy28352
#  7:          up2  FALSE    A           1    4 xy28352
#  ...
```

**base R**

```
abc_df <- data.frame(type=LETTERS[1:3], data_points_=0)

# CROSS JOIN
df2 <- merge(df, abc_df, all=TRUE)
# RE-ORDER ROWS
df2 <- with(df2, df2[order(unique_point, type, biased),])
row.names(df2) <- NULL

# CONDITIONAL ASSIGNMENT
df2$data_points <- ifelse(df2$type=='A', df2$data_points, df2$data_points_)
# SUBSET AND RE-ORDER COLS
df2 <- df2[c("unique_point", "biased", "type", "data_points", "team", "groupID")]
df2
#    unique_point biased type data_points team groupID
# 1           up1  FALSE    A           3    1 xy28352
# 2           up1   TRUE    A           4   22 xy28352
# 3           up1  FALSE    B           0    1 xy28352
# 4           up1   TRUE    B           0   22 xy28352
# 5           up1  FALSE    C           0    1 xy28352
# 6           up1   TRUE    C           0   22 xy28352
# 7           up2  FALSE    A           1    4 xy28352
# ...
```